# line numbering of minipages

Tags: listings, line-numbering

I can't manage to add linenumbers left of the boxes. Can anybody help me?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\fbox{

\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}

\textbf{def} mapper (key, value):

\hspace{7mm}\textbf{for} word \textbf{in} value.split():

\hspace{14mm}\textbf{yield} word, 1\\

\textbf{def} reducer (key , values):

\hspace{7mm}\textbf{yield} key, sum(values)\\


\textbf{if} name == "main":

\hspace{7mm}\textbf{import} dumbo

\hspace{7mm}dumbo.run (mapper, reducer, combiner=reducer )

\end{minipage}

}}

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think this should probably be retitled? Not sure to what, though... perhaps "how to do line-numbered code listings?"

Comment: Btw, @user2678, I would suggest you fill in some sort of mnemonic in your profile -- whether it be some form of your name or just a pseudonym -- which make you look more like a particular person and less like some random luser. (Registering an account was a good start, though.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny,numbersep=1em,
  morekeywords={def,for,yield,if,import},
  keywordstyle=\bfseries,frame=TLBR}
\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}
def mapper (key, value):
  for word in value.split():
    yield word, 1
def reducer (key , values):
  yield key, sum(values)
  if name == "main":
    import dumbo
    dumbo.run (mapper, reducer, combiner=reducer )
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```